# Getting a list of directories and files from root directory from remote site via FTP using CURL and PHP

Tags: php, curl, ftp, directory

I am currently getting a false result from my var_dump. Is there any way to get the result of folders and files on the root directory from a FTP account.

```
 <?php

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://www.xxxx.co.uk");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "[xxxx]:[xxxx]");
// grab URL and pass it to the browser
$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Comment: Just done a CURL error and its giving me access denied 530 despite the fact that I have used the same user and password and url to log in via the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `ftp_connect`

```
$ftp = ftp_connect("ftp.xxxx.co.uk") or die('could not connect.');
$raw = ftp_login($ftp, "anonymous", "") or die('could not login.');
$raw = ftp_pasv($ftp, true) or die('could not enable passive mode.');
$raw = ftp_rawlist($ftp, "/public_html/");
var_dump($raw);
```

Comment: I suppose I will have to use FTP connect. I thought using CURL functions would have some benefits over FTP such as speed.

Comment: You are correct ..... but this way you can ascertain there is nothing wrong with your auth information